# How to write-off an expensive file I/O in the middle of a C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am working on some code which is performance wise extremely demanding (I am using microsecond timers!). The thing is, it has a server<->client architecture where a lot of data is being shared at high speeds. To maintain a sync between the client and the server a simple "sequence number" based approach is followed. Such that if the client's program crashes, the client can "resume" communication by sending the server the last sequence number and they can "resume operations" without missing out on anything. 
The issue with this is that I am forced to write sequence numbers to disk. Sadly this has to be done on every "transaction". This file write causes huge time costs (as we would expect). 
So I thought I would use threads to get around this problem. However, if I create a regular thread, I would have to wait until the file write finishes anyway and if I used a detached thread, I am doing something risky, as the thread might not finish when my actual process is killed (let's say) and thus the sequence number gets messed up.

What are my options here. Kindly note that sadly I do not have access to C++11. I am using lpthread on linux.

Comment: producer/consumer queue. main thread produces sequence numbers, the writer thread consumes them and writes them to disk. Make sure that at the end of the program, the consumer thread is signalled to stop and that it has joined the main thread.

Comment: if i understand your problem right, you have to flush the stuff on the disk, so you cannot queue stuff. i don't think there is a good way to workaround the disk speed issue with common hardware, if you need to flush... better hardware is one option, or [ram disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) is also crosses in my mind...

Comment: Avoid [inventing the wheel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html), it is usually square.

Comment: "performance wise extremely demanding" ... "no access to C++11".  Something is rather wrong here: if performance is any consideration, you don't stick to decade-old compilers. If it's _extremely demanding_, you pick a cutting-edge compiler.

Comment: @MSalters I know. But I am not management. Just an engineer. A junior one at that. Have tried at least 20 times to have the servers updated to the latest libs but nothing.

Comment: @Wildling: Oh, in that case don't worry. If management assigns a junior engineer and no budget, that means performance is actually not at all important.

Comment: @MSalters Yes it is :) Trust me. Although only Wall Street bothers itself with such banal issues. Anyway, I simply created a thread and detached it from the main process and handled the "exception cases" that arise from it separately. It passed unit testing so let's see.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the data to a queue, and have the secondary threads dequeue, write, and signal when they're done.

You can also get some inspiration from log-based file systems. They get around this problem by having the main thread first writing a small record to a log file and returning control immediately to the rest of the program. Meanwhile, secondary threads can carry out the actual data write, and signal when done by also writing to the log file. This helps your maintain throughput by deferring writes to when more system resources are available, and doesn't block the main thread. Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_file_system)